# Может ли сборка иметь внутри себя контейнер с зависимостями?

Tags: любой-язык, dependency-injection

Собственно, вопрос в том, позволительно ли обычной подключаемой сборке внутри себя иметь контейнер с зависимостями и разрешать свои зависимости или это дурной тон и контейнер должен быть только в конечном приложении ?

Попытаюсь объяснить, что я имею ввиду:

Попалась вот такая архитектура

1. Класс, который находится в отдельной сборке. Реализует некоторый интерфейс и имеет несколько autofac модулей в этой же сборке.
2. Класс, который находится в отдельной сборке, который реализует некоторый интерфейс и строит контейнер зависимостей.
3. UI. Которому в Runtime можно подключить любую сборку, которая реализует интерфейс.

В итоге получается, что-то такое:

Пользователь открывает UI и подключает сборку из пункта 1, эта сборка передается классу из пункта 2, который строит контейнер. Далее UI рулит работой через интерфейс класса 2, не подозревая о наличии контейнеров.

В итоге получается, что-то типа универсального UI, которому из вне можно подсунуть какой-то плагин.

Comment: Библиотека обычно предоставляет классы, а их создает пользователь себе сам. Что вы имеете ввиду под *разрешать свои зависимости*? Приведите пример

Comment: @АндрейNOP Допустим, есть UI, которому на вход подается любая либа, которая реализует определенный интерфейс. Так вот, эта либа внутри себя использует другие либы и имеет контейнер внедрения зависимостей, который не показывает UI, пряча его за интерфейсом. И вот я подумал, а это не противоречит каким-нибудь принципам.

Comment: Ничего не понятно все равно. На вход UI подается либа? Либа реализует интерфейс? Контейнер зависимостей, который не показывает UI? Что это вообще всё значит? Похоже на очередной вопрос ради вопроса. Приведите реальный пример все же. Обычно мы имеем одну точку компоновки, где всё конфигурируется, выбираются конкретные реализации и эта точка компоновки там, откуда приложение стартует, а не в какой-то либе

Comment: @АндрейNOP Попытался развеять непонятки.

Comment: Хм... А за что дизы? Вроде, я дополнил инфу.

Answer (score -1):

Не совсем понятна суть вопроса. Зависимости, по сути, конфигурация, какие-то конкретные опции из возможных, либо тех что нужно написать самому. Т.е. где-то наружу из библиотеки торчат интерфейсы которые нужно ей предоставить для инициализации и/или конфигурации. Соотвественно и иметь контейнер она может (строго говоря для реализации он не обязателен, но будем считать что мы про принципы, а не детали, т.е. речь про абстрактный Dependency Resolver). Например: NLog, Entity Framework, ASP.NET MVC.